# Understanding why the group ring kG is semisimple

Tags: representation-theory

The definitions in my representation theory notes that are relevant are:
If A is a ring, the free A-module of rank 1 is A as an A-module.
A module M is simple if M is non-zero and it has no non-trivial proper submodules.
We say an A-module is completely reducible if it is either the zero module, or it is a direct sum of finitely many simple submodules.
If A is a ring, we say that A is semisimple if the free A-module of rank 1 is completely reducible.

The version of Maschke's Theorem in the notes states:
Let G be a finite group and suppose that $|G| \not= 0$ in the field k. Let U be a G-stable subspace of a finite-dimensional G-representation V. Then U admits at least one G-stable complement W in V.

Apparently as a corollary of Mashke's theorem, and using the above definitions, we see that the group ring kG is semisimple if $|G| \not= 0$ in k. My question is how we deduce this.

As far as I can tell, we want to show that kG is completely reducible as a kG-module. However, is it not true that kG is simple as a kG-module, so it follows that it is semisimple, since it is already reduced?

EDIT: We can find a representation corresponding to the kG-module, by setting $\rho : G \to GL(kG)$, defined by $\rho$(g)(v) = g$\cdot$v $\forall$g$\in$G, v$\in$ kG. Then we know that as left-multiplication by g$\in$G is an automorphism of G, then $<g\in G>$ is a G-stable subspace of kG, so using Maschke's theorem and induction on dimension of V, we see that the representation is completely reducible. Then we know that the subrepresentations correspond to kG-submodules of kG. Can we assume that these kG-submodules are then irreducible?

Comment: Do you know the correspondence between representations of $G$ over $k$ and $kG$-modules?

Comment: @Mark I have edited my question, is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Yes. The invariant subspaces of the representation correspond to the submodules. So an irreducible representation corresponds to a simple $kG$-module. Also, the correspondence preserves direct sums. So the fact that every finite representation of $G$ is completely reducible implies that every finitely generated $kG$-module is semisimple.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this